# Cocos2d App is Freezing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a game app using cocos2d Chipmunk. The app is working normally but after 30 to 40 seconds the app becomes unresponsive(app freezes) without any error log.
Can any tell me why this is happening and how to overcome this problem.
Please tell me the code also.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please tell us the code also.

Comment: Without knowing any of your game's code this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: i think it because of large png size used for animation(created by using Zwoptex). It's size is (2048 X 4096)

Comment: i got the solution. i was using timers but was not unscheduling them that's why app was freezing. now it is working fine after unscheduling that timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution. i was using timers but was not unscheduling them that's why app was freezing. now it is working fine after unscheduling that timers.

Comment: I also did the same thing when I started learning Cocos2d. After facing such issue, I realized to use ccTime. `[self scheule:@selector() ];`